# how to access undefined static variable in php using megic method?

Tags: php, oop

**This is my code**

```
 class newsds{


    public static  $name = "john";
    public static function test(){
        echo "test";
    }
    public static function __callstatic($method,$param){
        echo $method;
    }
    public function __call($method,$param){
        echo $method;
    }
    public function __get($value){
        echo $value;
    }



}
//echo newsds::dfdjsfkjfdghf();

//echo newsds::$name;

echo newsds::$data;

echo '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no magic method to handle undefined static variables, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

Comment: so how can i access undefined variable?

Comment: That is related on how statics are referenced when the object is created.
Once static definitions have been made it is not possible to create more on that instance.

when you are using magic method __callStatic, it was already defined as static. and the object itself uses that method if exists instead of throw an error.

Comment: It could be possible to create a magic methods __getStatic, __setStatic, and __unsetStatic, __issetStatic, but it have two problematic areas:
a) nobody would accept this RFC on php-src
b) you would depend on your own implementation to get, set, unset, isset that rely on a static internal property, and that would be a nightmare without any substantial benefit.

Comment: can you please delete your aswer beacuse i want delete quesion so

Comment: Why would you like to remove the question? Asking for something that is not possible or with bad undestanding of the language does not make the doubt invalid.